# What can cause a Swift func in a different file not to resolve for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have a couple of Swift files, which each belong to an iOS and an OS X target:

**File A**

```
public func doThing() {
    let constant: CustomValue? = otherThing {
        //...
    }
}
```

**File B**

```
public func otherThing(block: () -> Void) -> CustomValue? {
    //...
}
```

When I compile and run for OS X, it goes fine. Compiling for iOS, though, complains for File A:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'otherThing'

To troubleshoot, I implemented a stub of `otherThing()` in File A above `doThing()`. File A compiles, but I got this error for File B:

> Invalid redeclaration of 'otherThing'

Now, if it doesn't resolve it in File A, how can it be "redeclared" in File B? How can I get File A to resolve `otherThing` from File B?

To see the specific project I'm having trouble with, please check it out [on GitHub](https://github.com/abbeycode/Nimble/tree/issue234) (revision `917be3b8175576ae7e0c6275d388718fcc465040`). You only need to clone (recursively, as there's a submodule) and build the iOS scheme.

Comment: The implication is that you say `func otherThing` in two places. You can't do that.

Comment: @matt My goal isn't to redeclare `otherThing`, but to get it to resolve from File A. I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: You don't need to do anything to get things to "resolve" from one file to another. Everything at the top level of all files is visible automatically in all other files in the same module.

Comment: @matt I know that I _shouldn't_ need to do anything, and yet both files are in the same target and the function isn't resolving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103232/discussion-between-dov-and-thecodingart).

Comment: You both need a five minute time out. :) Meanwhile, @Dov, I've downvoted and closevoted your question because without seeing your actual code it's impossible to help. Feel free to provide more info and I'll consider retracting those votes. :) BTW Swift is Swift so there is nothing about what you're doing to suggest any reason why the same code that works in an OS X project wouldn't work in a parallel iOS project.

Comment: @matt what additional information would be helpful?

Comment: Enough to allow me to reproduce the project and hence the issue (also known as a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: @matt I added a link to the GitHub branch that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Nimble-iOS scheme builds fine for me. What's the problematic line supposed to be?

Comment: @matt I'm getting the error on `ThrowAssertion.swift:10` (it can't resolve `catchBadInstruction`). What Xcode version are you on? I'm using 7.2.1

Comment: OK, sorry, I see now. See my answer below.

Comment: Hellooooo? Have you put down the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `catchBadInstruction` function is declared / defined inside a conditional compilation block:

```
#if arch(x86_64)
// ...
public func catchBadInstruction(block: () -> Void) -> BadInstructionException? {
    // ...
}
// ...
#endif
```

On iOS, therefore, it does not compile and is not present.

To see that this is true, declare — *outside* the conditional compilation block — a stub like this:

```
public func catchBadInstructionn(block: () -> Void) -> BadInstructionException? {
    return nil
}
```

Note that it has a different name (two "n"s at the end of its name), so we won't get the "redeclaration" error. Now go back to *ThrowAssertion.swift* and replace the call with a call to *this* function:

```
let caughtException: BadInstructionException? = catchBadInstructionn // ...
```

It compiles fine — because `catchBadInstructionn` is present and visible, because it is not inside the conditional compilation block. If you move it *inside* the conditional compilation block, compilation fails in exactly the same way as before, proving that the conditional compilation is indeed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that does explain it. What's strange though, is that I get this even when I'm building for an >= iPhone 5s simulator, which should be x86_64...

Comment: You are not compiling only for x86_64, though. Anyway, I feel I've proved my answer is correct, so I hope you'll accept it.